# Getting key of maximum value from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
ex = [{'Michigan': 0.8},{'New York': 0.2}]
```

I want to extract `"Michigan"`, because 0.8 is the largest.

I tried the following, but is not simple and the last part doesn't work because `*item.values()` are not accepted (`SyntaxError`).

```
scores = []
for item in ex:
    scores.append(*item.values())

max_score = max(scores)

for item in ex:
    if (*item.values()) == max_score:
        print(item.keys())
```

Input:

```
ex = [{'Michigan': 0.8},{'New York': 0.2}]
```

Expected Output:

```
'Michigan'
```

Added:
I also tried sorting the list by value using itemgetter, but it is not working:

```
print(sorted(ex, key = lambda item: item.keys())
```

Comment: Is there always one key in each dictionary? Why not use `max` with a `key` to extract the whole dictionary (see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) then access its key afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [15]: list(max(ex, key=lambda x: list(x.values())).keys())[0]                                                                                                                
Out[15]: 'Michigan'
```